# Maven is unable to find another imported Maven project (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've done this many times. But for some reason now, no matter what I try, running maven install with Eclipse refuses to find an imported project.

> /C:/Users/Tarrant/Desktop/Attributes/src/main/java/me/warren1001/attributes/Attributes.java:[10,31]
>   package me.warren1001.configapi does not exist

This is up until line 22 of the mentioned Attributes.java file.

```
package me.warren1001.attributes;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import me.warren1001.configapi.Config;

public class Attributes {

    private Main plugin;

    private Config config;

    public Attributes(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        config = new Config(plugin, "attributes.yml");
    }
    ...
}
```

Obviously, it is unable to initialize the Config variable, which is the plugin I'm importing through Build Path -> Import Jar (using workspace).

You can clearly see it is imported in my project.

and here's the package for the ConfigAPI project...

```
package me.warren1001.configapi;
```

[And here's an image of Eclipse's Project Explorer... showing everything is right with the world (apparently not)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBLv3.png)

Seems like I'm missing something insanely obvious and when someone points it out I'm going to feel stupid, but I've been trying to fix this for the past 3 hours now with no avail. Any assistance?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project

Comment: Not sure as to how that would solve my problem... I've used this way plenty of times with no problems. It's only now it doesnt wanna work ;-; I've not done anything different.

Comment: Try right click on Attributes project Maven-> Update maven project and see if the project structure is the same as you've given above

Comment: I've hit that button countless times xD there would be an error icon over the project if I hadn't.

Comment: check the target folder, If you have that jar in it

Comment: It's there... https://i.gyazo.com/4a12907be8bdb499d524be04ab5878d2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add jars through Eclipse's "Build Path > Import Jar" for a Maven project. This will add the jar to the `.classpath` file that Eclipse uses, but Maven does not.

The correct way is to `install` your Maven project containing `Config` and add it as a dependency in the POM. Alternately, upload your `ConfigAPI` library to a centralized repository if you have one.

Make sure your dependent project has the "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects" enabled in your project's properties.

If your dependency's POM coordinates (`<groupId>`, `<artifactId>` and `<version>`) match up with your POM's, the M2Eclipse-plugin will automatically link the dependency for you, without having to install the dependency. However, you will eventually need to do this anyway if you have separate release cycles.

If everything is ok, you should see `ConfigAPI-1.2.0.jar` being listed under the "Maven Dependencies" instead of under your project in your Project Explorer at it was shown in your screenshot.

Comment: Interesting... I do that with another the API system I use (not my own ConfigAPI), so that won't be too difficult. I'll be sure to try that. Thanks :)

Comment: Yup, this worked. Thanks. I'll be sure to use this method from now on :)